# Adjusting y-axis line position in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to remove the space between the y-axis line and the first tick mark in my plot. Here's an example:

```
set.seed(201)
n <- 100
dat <- data.frame(xval = (1:n+rnorm(n,sd=5))/20, yval = 2*2^((1:n+rnorm(n,sd=5))/20))
dat[dat[,1] < 0,1] <- 0
dat[dat[,2] < 0,2] <- 0

ggplot(dat, aes(xval, yval)) + geom_point()
```

This code plots a graphic with a space between the y-axis line and the zero tick mark in the x-axis. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alter this "gap" using the `scale_x_continuous` function:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(xval, yval)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

From the help file on `scale_x_continuous`,

> expand: numeric vector of length two giving multiplicative and
>   additive expansion constants. These constants ensure that the data is
>   placed some distance away from the axes.

To alter the space on the y-axis, use `scale_y_continuous`

Comment: I'm curious as to why is the `0` on the y still a little higher?

Comment: Did you add `scale_y_continuous` as well?